# aws cli describe-instances without a VpcId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to run `aws ec2 describe-instances` looking for any instances without a `VpcId` property (those in ec2-classic)

How can I return ec2-classic instances using either the `--query` flag or JMESPath expression to get results *without* a `VpcId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cli command will list all the instances which doesn't have `VpcId`.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?!not_null(VpcId)] | [].[InstanceId]'  --output text
```

You can tweak the same to list all instances which has `VpcId`.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?not_null(VpcId)] | [].[InstanceId]'  --output text
```

Comment: Changed this to the accepted answer as it is pure aws cli solution.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Not sure if this is a Windows thing, but I had to change the end to `--output table` (text was not an option).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to query all instances and look for entries that do not have a `SubnetId`. The following CLI lists the EC2 classic instances. You can change the `--query` option to get the attributes you want.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], State.Name, SubnetId]' --output text | grep -v subnet
```

**Output**

```
i-123456789abcdef01 MyClassicRunning    running None
i-123456789abcdef23 MyClassicStopped    stopped None
```